# Warning: attempt to present VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am getting this warning, and I am not sure why. I tried getting rid of it by adding the subview but that didn't solve my problem either. Help please

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Here is the code I am using on one VC:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:rootViewContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

Edit: my app still works properly in regards to presenting view controllers I just want to know why the compiler is generating this warning

Answer (score 1):

The warning shows up because you are presenting a new view controller (`rootViewController`) an another view controller that you actually just dismissed!

`[self presentViewController:rootViewContoller animated:YES completion:nil];` is in the **completion handler** block of the dismissal of the other view controller, that means it gets called **after** that view controller has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:rootViewContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```